# MondoDB Aggregate - Absolute count for each day

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have the following (already aggregated)collection

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-01" }, "total" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-02" }, "total" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-03" }, "total" : 10 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-04" }, "total" : 10 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-05" }, "total" : 5 }
```

What i need is calculating an absolute value for each day, summing the previous days. So expected result would be in the case above

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-01" }, "absolutetotalforday" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-02" }, "absolutetotalforday" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-03" }, "absolutetotalforday" : 15 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-04" }, "absolutetotalforday" : 25 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : "2015-02-05" }, "absolutetotalforday" : 30 }
```

Currently no clue how to achieve this with 1 query. Of course i could do a sum for each day I'm interested in, but this might be a long time range

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can't use an aggregate? $group by _id, with a sum to `total`?

Comment: $sum applies only inside 1 group. But i have to sum up each day, so i'm not sure what your idea is...

Comment: My bad I didn't read your question well enough. Forget my comment ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because aggregation framework has no mechanism of knowing the value of a previous document, or the previous "grouped" value of a document, your best bet would be to use **[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)** in this case.

**[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)** will give you the "running total" for the current total at end of day you require although this won't be in the desired key, `absolutetotalforday` but in a key called `value` since the reduced values are always in`value` key.

The following **[`mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce)** operation will give you the desired result, assuming the results from the previous aggregation operation were output to a separate collection named `agg_results`:

```
db.agg_results.mapReduce(
    function() { emit( this._id, this.total ); },  
    function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); },
    { 
        "scope": { "total": 0 },
        "finalize": function(key, value) {
            total += value;
            return total;
        },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
);
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : "2015-02-01"
            },
            "value" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : "2015-02-02"
            },
            "value" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : "2015-02-03"
            },
            "value" : 15
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : "2015-02-04"
            },
            "value" : 25
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : "2015-02-05"
            },
            "value" : 30
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 0,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 5,
        "emit" : 5,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

Sorting the results will not work with inline results and with dates of String type. Instead, try converting the date strings to a JavaScript date object, write the results to a collection and then run a sort on that collection:

```
db.agg_results.mapReduce(
    function() { emit( new Date(this._id.day), this.total ); },  
    function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); },
    { 
        "scope": { "total": 0 },
        "finalize": function(key, value) {
            total += value;
            return total;
        },
        "out": "tmpResults"
    }
);
```

**Sample Output (with sort)**

```
> db.tmpResults.find().sort({_id: 1})
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00Z"), "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-02-02T00:00:00Z"), "value" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-02-03T00:00:00Z"), "value" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00Z"), "value" : 25 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-02-05T00:00:00Z"), "value" : 30 }
>
```

Comment: Hey, sounds pretty awesome. But how do i make sure the sort order for the incoming collection? collection "agg_results" may not be sorted chronologically

Comment: @Bearzi I've updated my answer with some sorting options.